# Difference between using lambdaHandler and handler

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, express, aws-lambda, handler

I was working on an express api and I came across my code and someone else's code. 
While making an export I have

```
exports.lambdaHandler = awsServerlessExpress({app})
```

and the other code had

```
exports.handler =  awsServerlessExpress({app})
```

This really got me thinking what is the difference between exporting my express api with these two different handlers.

Comment: The handler will be exposed under a different name. The lambda in AWS has to be told what its entry point is called. You can call it whatever you want as long as your code matches your lambda config.

Comment: It's just a name. It can be anything. From AWS Console you can set the entry point to that name.

Answer (score 0):

Like others in the comment section pointed out that this is the name that the handler will be exposed as. For example, if you name your handler `foobar`:

```
exports.foobar = async (event) => {
    console.log('hello, world')
};
```

In the `Runtime settings` -> `Handler`, you should set it to `<filename>.foobar`, otherwise you will get

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
  "errorMessage": "index.handler is undefined or not exported",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.HandlerNotFound: index.handler is undefined or not exported",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:144:11)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)",
    "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)",
    "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
  ]
}
```